# Replace strings in only targeted ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the [space]-[space] part in the example below

```
This - is - an - example - message
```

(including the spaces before and after the minus symbol)

with

```
<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>
```

The HTML is:

```
<p class="product-title" id="fixthistitle">This - is - an - example - message</p>
```

I only want to change this for ID's containing 'fixthistitle'.

So the end result would be:

```
<p class="product-title" id="fixthistitle">This<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>is<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>an<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>example<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>message</p>
```

Normally one would just simple changed the HTML in there to get the formatting you want, however this is pre-generated text, so I cannot change this. Therefor I need a JS/jQuery solution for this?

Maybe someone can share how to achieve this? I hope this makes sense for someone.

**EDIT :**

Sorry my bad, an ID should always be unique.

Anyways; thank you kindly for the many answers / solutions. Highly appreciated!

Comment: There should be only  ONE `id` as `fixthistitle`. You can use `class` instead if you want to have the same name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the text on `-` and then rejoin it with the `div`:

```js
  $('#fixthistitle').html( $('#fixthistitle').html().split(' - ').join('<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="product-title" id="fixthistitle">This - is - an - example - message</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

`id` should be unique so use `class` instead

1. You can use **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** for iterate and update the content
2. Split the content using **[`split('-')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** (or using regex **[`split(/\s+-\s+/)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** )
3. Now join the array with `<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>`, using **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**

```js
$('#fixthistitle').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.split('-').join('<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>')
});
```

```css
.withthiscss {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="product-title" id="fixthistitle">This - is - an - example - message</p>
```

Using regex

```js
$('#fixthistitle').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.split(/\s+-\s+/).join('<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>')
});
```

```css
.withthiscss {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="product-title" id="fixthistitle">This - is - an - example - message</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in comment, use `class` instead of `id` if you want to perform this task on several items/elements. A jQuery + regex approach would be:

```
$('.fixthistitle').each(function(i, v) {
  var s = $(this).text();
  $(this).html(s.replace(/\s-\s/, '<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```js
$('#fixthistitle').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.split(/\s+-\s+/).join('<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>');
});
```

```css
.withthiscss {
    color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="product-title" id="fixthistitle">This - is - an - example - message</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#fixthistitle').html(function() {
  var find = " - ";
  var regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
  return $(this).html().replace(regex, '<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>');
});
```

```css
.withthiscss {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="product-title" id="fixthistitle">This - is - an - example - message</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can do:

```
var k = $("#fixthistitle").text();
str= k.replace(/[ ]+-[ ]+/g,'<div class="withthiscss">xx</div>');
$("#fixthistitle").html(str);
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/qb0hwvnu/)

Comment: just a little thing, you missed "," at the end of "var k = $("#fixthistitle").text()". Though it will work, but might cause issue with larger code base. So you can add a comma or add semi-colon but in this case you should add "var" keyword in the next line

Answer (score 1):

To replace the " - " part you can use regular expression

```
"This - is - an - example - message".replace(/ - /g,"<div class='withthiscss'>xx</div>")
```

Now since it is available in HTML first we need to get the text from HTML tag. SO here is the code

```
var originalText = $('#fixthistitle').text(),
    transformedText = originalText.replace(/ - /g,"<div class='withthiscss'>xx</div>")

$('#fixthistitle').text(transformedText)
```

Answer (score 1):

IDs are supposed to be unique!!!

```
$("#fixthistitle").each(function() {
    var str = $(this).text();
    var res = str.replace(" - ", "whatever");
    $(this).text(res);
});
```

But this will stop after it finds the first occurrence. So you need to identify the row you want by a class attribute or a data- attribute. Then it will work.

Otherwise you can try this:

```
$("p").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'fixthistitle')
    {
        var str = $(this).text();
        var res = str.replace(/\s-\s/g, ' ');
        $(this).text(res);
    }
});
```

Dependency: jQuery 1.9.x but it should work with most versions of jQuery